# Having issues with installing "imagemagick" on Ubuntu v12 VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, installation, imagemagick

I have a Rails app that use Paperclip. Paperclip needs **imagemagick** for its functionality.

I've been trying all afternoon to install it, but still don't know how to solve this issue:

> sudo apt-get install imagemagick

```
...
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main x11proto-kb-dev all 1.0.6-2 [269 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main xtrans-dev all 1.2.7-1 [84.3 kB]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main libxcb1-dev amd64 1.8.1-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libxcb1-dev amd64 1.8.1-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main libx11-dev amd64 2:1.5.0-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libx11-dev amd64 2:1.5.0-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main libx11-doc all 2:1.5.0-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libx11-doc all 2:1.5.0-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main x11proto-xext-dev all 7.2.1-1 [265 kB]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main libxext-dev amd64 2:1.3.1-2ubuntu0.12.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libxext-dev amd64 2:1.3.1-2ubuntu0.12.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main libxml2-dev amd64 2.8.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu2.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libxml2-dev amd64 2.8.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu2.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Fetched 880 kB in 4s (218 kB/s)
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.8.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/libdpkg-perl_1.16.7ubuntu6.2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg-dev_1.16.7ubuntu6.2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/build-essential/build-essential_11.5ubuntu3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.18.4-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freetype/libfreetype6-dev_2.4.10-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8-dev_1.2.1-0ubuntu2.12.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-dev_1.2.49-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/x11proto-core/x11proto-core-dev_7.0.23-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxau/libxau-dev_1.0.7-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/x11proto-input/x11proto-input-dev_2.2-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcb/libxcb1-dev_1.8.1-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-dev_1.5.0-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-doc_1.5.0-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxext/libxext-dev_1.3.1-2ubuntu0.12.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2-dev_2.8.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

The parameter `--fix-missing` doesn't help either.

Somewhere I've read that before the installation itself I should run `sudo apt-get update`, but this returns following error:

```
...
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I unfortunately have no idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: U r using 12.10 right? Try downloading package abd install manually. Sorry can't help much because m writing from mobile

Comment: Thank you for your advise, RAJ. I downloaded Imagemagick, unpacked it and ran `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-x=no --disable-static --with-modules --without-perl --without-magick-plus-plus --with-quantum-depth=8 --disable-openmp`. Then after running the `make` command, I got `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`. Any advice here, please? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The errors you are seeing when you run "sudo apt-get update" are because you are running version 12.04, which is a LTS version.  Long term service version.  They have released version 14.04 now so 12.04 is no longer supported for security updates.

I would recommend updating to version 14.04.  This will resolve the issue you are seeing with the security updates as well as provide a more secure and stable platform for your application.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

That will upgrade your ubuntu version.  After restarting, then run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing
```

That will update the repo's and install imagemagick for you.

Comment: Long Term Service means its a stable version which will be maintained and will be supported for long time. Upgrading the ubuntu must not be the good solution